# Feedback always welcome link should be renamed

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, hyperlinks, languages

The "Feedback always welcome" link at the bottom of [Careers Germany](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/de/) has the text "Stack Overflow Meta". I think it should be renamed to one of the following.

> - Feedback (ist) immer willkommen
> - Rückmeldungen (sind) immer willkommen
> - Kommentare (sind) immer willkommen

It's possible to omit *ist* and *sind* to shorten the text.

Comment: No point in different tag for the German version of careers, the team is used to look in [meta-tag:careers] list and they're super fast usually.

Comment: Also, looks like the [French version](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/fr/) is OK.

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes french, us and uk versions are fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Our German team likes "Kommentare sind immer willkommen".  We'll get it fixed.  Along with changing Meta SO to Meta SE.